# Can I run two/multiple rabbitmq consumers parallely using asyncio library in python. If yes, how?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, pika

I am trying to run multiple rabbitMQ consumers in a single call. But in python, other consumers won't start until first one is closed, due to its synchronous nature. Can I use `asyncio` library to run multiple consumers in parallel? Is yes, how can I do that?

I am currently using threads to run multiple consumers and using `pika 1.2.0`.

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you can use the aio-pika? https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/1-introduction.html

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) are you encountering?

Comment: @dirn Let's say I want to use 3 consumers. I want to do the consuming parallely. So i have tried using threads to start the consumers which is working absolutely fine. Here I want to know if there is a way to run consumers in parallel without threads. May be using asyncio library in python or something like that.

Comment: That doesn’t show us what you’ve tried. We can’t fix the problems with your code if we can’t see your code.